# What is wrong With make?

Tags: c, linux, module, header, makefile

C

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

---

```
/* makefile */
/* uname -r = 2.6.32-5-686 */
obj-m += hello.o
all :
    make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/build /home/mgh/Documents modules
clean : 
    make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/build /home/mgh/Documents clean
```

---

```
root@localhost:/home/mgh/Documents# make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/build /home/mgh/Documents modules
make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686'
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:44: /usr/src/linux-headers-``2.6.32-5-common/scripts/basic/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[5]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/scripts/basic``/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[4]: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `/home/mgh/Documents'.
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config``/kernel.release'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: To quote Scott Meyers: "`make`? Who needs stinkin’ `make`?".

Answer (score 5):

Guesswork: You did not set the M environment variable in your custom Makefile. See http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html

And the next time, please do indeed ask a more specific question than 'What is wrong?'

Comment: I do that Like this   `make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/build M=/home/mgh/Documents modules` but error still here! :(  My Os IS debian squeeze and i think i haven't some file such as headrs or ... (i am newbie in linux )

Comment: No, what you wrote in your comment is not what you wrote in your question. If you are new, please check out one of the kernel module tutorials and follow it by the word. Then, if you run into problems, please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 4):

I dispute that anything is wrong with `make`. I am very certain, though, that something is wrong with your Makefile. According to some random internet searching, try something like this:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/build SUBDIRS=/home/mgh/Documents modules
```

This is assuming that your Makefile resides in `/home/mgh/Documents`.

Comment: Did you try changing the lines as I suggested?